# Donner du vingt pour cent

Tags: expressions

In *Le nœud de vipères* de Mauriac, we find a young man described as giving « du vingt pour cent » :

[image: extrait du livre]

> Il a pourtant l'argent de tout le monde à sa disposition, ce garçon qui donne du vingt pour cent !

What does this expression mean?

- He gives 20% (e.g. as a tithe instead of only 10%)?
- He gives 20% out of 100%, i.e. very little effort?
- He gives 20 in exchange for 100, i.e. he makes great profit on his trades?
- ???

Comment: « Donner du 20% pour un agent de change signifie qu’il est déjà très riche, « pourtant »  et l’exclamation accentue sur l’incompréhension et la colère du narrateur : comme un fils aussi riche qui n’est surement pas dans le besoin peut-il tourner autour d’un héritage. » [→](http://ginnungagap.over-blog.com/article-34538848.html).

Comment: @None Thanks for the reference!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The closest definition would be:

> [Donner, TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/donner)
> ...
> **C.−**, **2.**, **b)** [Le sujet désigne une chose abstraite] Rapporter. L'emprunt ottoman donne 25%. Voilà tout ce que je sais, mon bibi! (Flaubert, Correspondances, 1866, p. 216).

I understand that the young man brings in/makes 20 francs per 100 invested (although that seems a lot), so he must be wealthy.

> *Hubert est « ce garçon qui donne du vingt pour cent », « cet agent de change, qui donne de tels dividendes » soit un bien mauvais homme d’affaires.*
> Gabriel Khairallah
> [*Crise de la famille et autonomisation de l'individu chez Mahfouz et Mauriac*, p 194](https://tel.archives-ouvertes.fr/tel-01720047/document)

Comment: Ahh, okay -- he "gives" *rates* of 20% on his exchanges, I guess.

Comment: By the way, why *du* ? Ellipsis for *du _____ de 20 %*, and if so, what might that noun be? Or is it just idiomatic without explanation?

Comment: @LukeSawczak I don't think it's an ellipsis of anything. The "normal" structure would be *il donne/fait 20%*). To me it's the same *du* as in *donner du Monsieur à quelqu'un*, it is ironical & it emphasises the sum: the interest rate is very high.

Comment: And/or the same *du* as *il fait du 150 km/h*.

Comment: Or *il joue du Beatles*, I guess — in other words, the masculine as the default for a genderless "some". Neat!